# Is there a restriction on Doha, Qatar for going outside due to the pandemic?

Tags: covid-19, qatar, doha

I wonder is there any restriction to going outside from home/hotel to malls, stores, etc. for specific time of day due to the global pandemic (in Doha)? Can I freely leave hotel and go for shopping, let's say? Is there any rule I must aware of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I freely leave hotel and go for shopping, let's say? Is there any rule I must aware of?

No curfew but some businesses are cut down to some extent e.g. https://www.gco.gov.qa/en/top-news/phase-4-statement/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200911061242/https://www.gco.gov.qa/en/top-news/phase-4-statement/)):

> - Continuing normal working hours at malls while keeping capacity to 50%, and opening food courts in malls with a capacity of 30%. Allowing
>   children to enter malls.
> - Allowing the increase in restaurants capacity starting with 30%, according to the procedures which will be set by the Ministry of
>   Commerce and Industry.